# 対象のコードを公開できない質問に, どのように対処したらよいか？

Tags: 討議, サポート, 回答の仕方

[実行スレッドによって、同じSQLite書き込み処理時間が大きく異なるのはなぜでしょうか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75179/)
にて, スレッドを使うと極端に処理が遅くなるという質問があります
コードを公開できない, のであまり具体的な言及ができていない。
理由はたぶんですが, 以下あたりが推測されます

- コードが巨大
- 業務かなにかなので差し障りがある

可能ならば, パーツに分解し, 問題が発生する最小限に抑えたものを(伏せるべきところは伏せて) 公開してもらうのが筋だったかもしれません
単体では動いても結合した際に出そうな問題に見えたので, そういった誘導？をスキップしてしまいました

---

#### どうするのがよかったのか？

回答として私が選択したのは …
質問にある条件のコードを記述してみて速度を調べ 比較, そこに現れていない問題が原因だよね, と

- 一歩間違えれば「クレクレ質問」と同等になりかねないので, 検証コードの公開は控えた
  (応えてしまえば, クレクレ質問の偽装手段を与えることになってしまいそう)
- 結局, 組み合わせて発生するような結合の問題であれば, 回答として不十分のような？

他の回答として思いつくのは以下のようなものです

1. うまく誘導し, 最小化コードを提供してもらうべきだった
2. パフォーマンス計測(調査)手段を提供すべきだった

もっといい回答の仕方があるのではないか。今回付けた回答は回答になってないのではないか？
… などを思い, 質問させてもらいました。

Answer (score 4):

> 今回付けた回答は回答になってないのではないか？

該当質問は一定規模の実システムにおける複合的な問題を取り扱っており、ソースコードや再現環境の提示が行われていないため、究極的には当事者自身でしか解決できない問題に思えます。

[oririさんの回答投稿](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/75336)が質問者にとって真の回答になったかは第三者では知り得ませんが、様々な仮説を提示し、疑似実験による検証を行い、考察を記述されている内容は有用なものに思えます。

Comment: 補記：「どうするのがよかったのか？」に関しては、oririさんが挙げている2点にも同意します。スタックオーバーフローは無償・互恵のQ&Aサイトである以上、質問趣旨を明確化してゆく責は質問者自身が負うべきです。回答者や第三者がそれを補助する行為は素晴らしいとは思いますが、全てのケースで物事がうまく運ぶとも限りませんし、それで十分ではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

例に挙げられた質問に関して言えば、質問者本人からは「詳細は記載しきれませんが」とは書かれているものの、"コードが巨大だから" や "業務に関わるので" といった点については特に触れられていません。

全ての質問にコードを含める必要があるわけではないのかもしれませんが、コードの有無も含めて質問にあいまいな部分を少しでも感じたのであれば、セオリーに従ってコメントで明確化を求めたり、必要ならいったんクローズすることも検討してください。

質問が曖昧な状態でも詳しい人が気を利かせて回答を付けることは可能なのかもしれませんが、内容とは直接関係の無い "質問の仕方" 等に対するアドバイスも含まれてしまったりして、ナレッジの蓄積という面ではあまり好ましくないと思っています (その質問をした人にとってしか有益なやり取りとして残らない) 。